# Hotkey detection for UI elements

Tags: c#, performance, collections, unity3d

I have several UI elements that can be opened using hotkeys for example the settings menu's key is *Escape*. The problem is that I have the `Keycode` stored in `Dictionary` along with an `Action` or a `Button.ButtonClickedEvent` here's how the two dictionaries are declared:

```
    public static readonly Dictionary<KeyCode, Button.ButtonClickedEvent> KeysUIElementsWithButtonEvents = new Dictionary<KeyCode, Button.ButtonClickedEvent>
    {
        { KeyCode.P, SpellbookButton.onClick },
        { KeyCode.Escape, SettingsMenuButton.onClick },
    };

    public static readonly Dictionary<KeyCode, Action> KeysUIElementsWithActions = new Dictionary<KeyCode, Action>
    {
        { KeyCode.LeftAlt, SwitchCursorState},
    };
```

And here's how I **used** to invoke them :

```
        foreach (var item in Settings.Settings.KeysUIElementsWithButtonEvents)
        {
            if(Input.GetKeyDown(item.Key))
            {
                if(Cursor.lockState == CursorLockMode.Locked)
                {
                    Settings.Settings.SwitchCursorState();
                }
                item.Value.Invoke();
            }
        }

        foreach (var item in Settings.Settings.KeysUIElementsWithActions)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(item.Key))
            {
                if (Cursor.lockState == CursorLockMode.Locked)
                {
                    Settings.Settings.SwitchCursorState();
                }
                item.Value.Invoke();
            }
        }
```

I didn't like the repetitive code in here so I decided to create a function which solves the problem:

```
    CheckUIKeysCollection(Settings.Settings.KeysUIElementsWithButtonEvents);                              
    CheckUIKeysCollection(Settings.Settings.KeysUIElementsWithActions);

    private void CheckUIKeysCollection<T>(Dictionary<KeyCode, T> collection)
    {
        foreach (var item in collection)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(item.Key))
            {
                if (Cursor.lockState == CursorLockMode.Locked)
                {
                    Settings.Settings.SwitchCursorState();
                }
                if (item.Value is Action)
                {
                    (item.Value as Action).Invoke();
                    continue;
                }
                (item.Value as Button.ButtonClickedEvent).Invoke();
            }
        }
    }
```

However I'm not sure if the method is efficient enough it involves some casting here and there and it's also being called in the `Update` function (every frame) and if I have big collections it might hurt the performance. What can I do to improve the method?

Comment: Maybe you could wrap your *Button.ButtonClickedEvent* and *Action* in a class that would do the work. This solution would allow you to have one dictionary instead of two and a simpler invoke process in the iteration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this with one dictionary is to simply create an action for the `Button.ButtonClickedEvent` calls:

> ```
> public static readonly Dictionary<KeyCode, Button.ButtonClickedEvent> KeysUIElementsWithButtonEvents = new Dictionary<KeyCode, Button.ButtonClickedEvent>
> {
>     { KeyCode.P, SpellbookButton.onClick },
>     { KeyCode.Escape, SettingsMenuButton.onClick },
> };
>
> public static readonly Dictionary<KeyCode, Action> KeysUIElementsWithActions = new Dictionary<KeyCode, Action>
> {
>     { KeyCode.LeftAlt, SwitchCursorState},
> };
> ```

Can be one `Dictionary<KeyCode, Action>`:

```
public static readonly Dictionary<KeyCode, Action> KeysUIElementsWithActions = new Dictionary<KeyCode, Action>
{
    { KeyCode.P, () => SpellbookButton.onClick.Invoke() },
    { KeyCode.Escape, () => SettingsMenuButton.onClick.Invoke() },
    { KeyCode.LeftAlt, SwitchCursorState }
}
```

Then this:

> ```
> private void CheckUIKeysCollection<T>(Dictionary<KeyCode, T> collection)
> {
>     foreach (var item in collection)
>     {
>         if (Input.GetKeyDown(item.Key))
>         {
>             if (Cursor.lockState == CursorLockMode.Locked)
>             {
>                 Settings.Settings.SwitchCursorState();
>             }
>             if (item.Value is Action)
>             {
>                 (item.Value as Action).Invoke();
>                 continue;
>             }
>             (item.Value as Button.ButtonClickedEvent).Invoke();
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Becomes this:

```
private void CheckUIKeysCollection(Dictionary<KeyCode, Action> collection)
{
    foreach (var item in collection)
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(item.Key))
        {
            if (Cursor.lockState == CursorLockMode.Locked)
            {
                Settings.Settings.SwitchCursorState();
            }
            item.Value.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

No more generics, no more casting, no more inferences. Simply create an action that calls the `ButtonClickedEvent.Invoke()` method for the appropriate `Button`.

You could, also, create a method that does that for you:

```
public void ClickButton(Button button)
{
    button.onClick.Invoke();
}
```

Then make your dictionary:

```
public static readonly Dictionary<KeyCode, Action> KeysUIElementsWithActions = new Dictionary<KeyCode, Action>
{
    { KeyCode.P, ClickButton(SpellbookButton) },
    { KeyCode.Escape, ClickButton(SettingsMenuButton) },
    { KeyCode.LeftAlt, SwitchCursorState }
}
```

This *also* means it's simpler to click buttons from anywhere in your code: simply call `ClickButton(Button)`, instead of `Button.onClick.Invoke()`.

---

Apart from that:

Using `is` then `as` is not recommended, simply use `as` then check if it's null:

```
var temp = value as string;

if (temp != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(temp.Length);
}
```